# How to use the word "offset" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

I am writing an academic piece of work

The theme is: **C= A - B. After laws, both A and B decrease while C insignificantly change (in another word, C stays the same).**

So, can I write:
"**The insignificant change in C is caused by the offset forces between the decrease in A and B after laws**" ?

Comment: I suggest that you remove the words "improve the sentence" from your question, as this is outside the scope of this site. The rest of your question is OK, as it is a specific question about usage of the word **offset**.

Comment: question edited, thank @JavaLatte

Comment: I'd only change your sentence to say, "*... is caused by the **offsetting** forces...*". I'm unclear what "after laws" means, so I hope it's academic speak that makes sense in the context.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the examples in  the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/offset). If one change cancels out another, the normal way to say this is to say "is offset by". For your sentence, you would say something like:

> The decrease in A **is offset** by the decrease in B, resulting in a very small change in C.